# As a student, how do I answer "do you have any questions"?

Tags: colloquial-language

Consider this conversation in an online classroom

> Teacher: "do you have any questions in this section?"
>
> Student: "No"

Is the answer a little bit impolite?

How about this one?

> Student: "No more questions"

How do native speakers answer/response that in classroom in real life?

Comment: Communication is not just conveyed by words alone in a vacuum. We also communicate with our body language and tone of voice to convey our embarrassment, indifference, defiance, rudeness, assurance  or shyness. A shrug of the shoulders and a mumbled "no" will be interpreted as indifference or rude compared to someone who looks you straight in the eye, and smiles "no".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the answer a little bit impolite?

NO! (That looks impolite, no?) How about just "No."? (Is that polite enough? No?)

You don't tell us if your teacher is asking this verbally, or in a chatroom in Zoom. Writing "NO!" may be seen as a bit impolite. If the conversation is spoken, then it is your tone and your expression that determines whether it is taken as impolite or not. If you say it nicely, I don't see how it can be impolite. Even a "YES!!" can be impolite, depending on how it is said.

I, however, don't feel this is a common reply:

> Teacher: "Do you have any questions in section?"
>
> Student: "No more questions."

I think that reply would work if your teacher asked

> Do you have any more questions?

and I feel even then that reply might sound awkward and robotic.

The best thing to do is to focus on your tone and facial expression. If you want to have definitive expressions then the following are some that you can try:

> Teacher: "Do you have any questions in this section?"
>
> Option 1: "No, no, I think I understand it now. Thank you!" (or "... I have got it now ...")
>
> Option 2: "No, I think I am good for now. Thank you!"
>
> Option 3: "No, I don't have any questions at the moment. Thanks!"

Again, whether your response is impolite or not depends on how you actually say it. It has very little to do with the actual phrasing of the reply.

Comment: Thank you. How about "I have got it. I am ready to **move on**"?

Comment: @PutBere *"I have got it. I am ready to move on"* is a little awkward. You should add a "No." in the front, and to make things a little smoother you could say *"No. I have got it. Thanks. I **think** I am ready to move on to the next section."* A smile and nice body language will always do the trick. Just make sure that you are engaging with your teacher when replying, and then if by mistake you say something a little awkward, it won't seem impolite.

Answer (score 0):

If you find "no" impolite (which it isn't necessarily), you can make it less so:

- No, sir/no, ma'am (prevalent in the southern United States, at least)
- No, thank you [for asking].

*No more questions* sounds abrupt to me, perhaps because it is an incomplete sentence that might be used as a proscriptive command.  Instead, I would suggest

- I have no more questions.

Or

- I don't have any more questions.