# Is it common to say "Let's move on" when students respond to a teacher?

Tags: word-usage

According to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/move-on), "move on" could mean

> to start a new activity
>
> I'd done the same job for years and felt it was time to move on.

or

> to accept that a situation has changed and be ready to deal with new experiences
>
> Since he and his girlfriend broke up, he's been finding it difficult to move on.

In an online classroom, a teacher just finished a section and going to start next section

> Teacher: "Do you have any questions **in this section**?"
>
> Student: "No, I don't have any questions at the moment. Thanks!"

According to the post [As a student, how do I answer "do you have any questions"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/249303/115654), the student's response is natural and polite. Is it still natural if the following part is added?

> Student: "No, I don't have any questions at the moment. Thanks! **Let's move on.**"

Comment: You might need to be a bit careful here. When a politician, for example, says ***Let's move on***, the strong implication is ***Let's forget about** [whatever we're currently talking about, because it's **no longer important**]*. And that's pretty much the sense implied in your "girlfriend" example. But that implication is probably not appropriate for your "student" example, where the focus is on ***moving forward to something new***, rather than ***moving away from something old and no longer important or interesting***.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Thank you. In this particular context (a moment between two sections in a class), is it natural to "let's move on"? Is there another expression more appropriate could be used here?

Comment: Well, if it's a teacher talking to the class, he doesn't *have* to say anything at all about "moving on" - he can just start delivering "Lesson 2" as soon as he wants to. I don't think it's meaningful to think of a "standard" way for a teacher to tell his class that he wants them to start doing something new. Many years ago, Monty Python poked fun at the whole idea of "segueing" from one "topic" to the next, with their [*And Now for Something Completely Different*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dlCbFu5dpc8) skits. A "quirkily amusing" teacher might jokingly copy *that!*

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Thank you. It seems that I don't convey the idea clearly. The question is about what a student speaks rather than a teacher.

Comment: Sorry - that was me not paying attention. I don't think it would normally be appropriate for a *student* (very much the "junior partner" in a conversation) to be saying anything like that to his teacher. He should just end with ***Thanks***, and leave it to the more senior addressee to decide when and if to "move on", and if so, to *what*.

Comment: **Generally**, the "leader" (teacher) would say "Let's move on"; not the "subordinate (student)."

Comment: Yeah you would just about never say this to a teacher - it’s really impolite and cocky.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing grammatically wrong with it, but I would advise against saying it. I think it sounds slightly disrespectful.

It’s not exactly that it sounds impatient, but rather it sounds like the student is trying to take control of the pacing of the class, which is disrespectful to the teacher, who is supposed to be in charge.

Answer (score 0):

It is natural to say “let’s move on.” The student is saying that they want  to start the next question or lesson.

Comment: Take a careful look at how you have worded your answer. It needs improving.

Comment: Thanks for the advise

Comment: Do you think it's "natural and polite", as per the OP's question? I sure don't

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it is a student-teacher conversation does not allow us to call the use of ***Let's move on!*** natural nor polite. It hints at a little impatience there that I would say is out of place.

However, I see nothing wrong with saying in such a conversation:

> No, I don't have any questions at the moment. Thank you! ***Shall we move on***?

Note: If I were a student, I would also avoid saying ***Thanks!*** to my teacher. ***Thank you*** is more polite.